# Filling up a whole page with dummy text using m-ipsum module

Tags: context, modules

**Warning, I'm crossposting from the ConTeXt mailing list**

I am trying to fill up an entire page with dummy text using m-ipsum. Unfortunately, it looks like m-ipsum only allows up to 12 lines, if I increase it to 13+ lines I see no change in the resulting PDF file:

```
\usemodule[m-ipsum]

\starttext
    \ipsum[alternative=lines, n=12]
\stoptext
```

Is this intended behavior or a bug. How can I fill up the whole page with dummy text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m-ipsum` module comes with a text file `lorem.tex` that has only 12 lines. This file is loaded by default but you can specify another file with the parameter `file`. To get more lines you can copy the text from the LaTeX `lipsum` package, where it is provided in the file `lipsum.ltd.tex`. You do need to strip the LaTeX commands in that file to make it usable for `m-lipsum`. Then you get something similar to the following:

`mylorem.tex`

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut
leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna
fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida
placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis
nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis
eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales,
sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus
libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec
aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit
mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper
vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis
erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus
viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus
adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam
turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas
lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a,
ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat
lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus
vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec
bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi.
Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu
massa.
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh.
Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc
elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit
purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl.
Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.
Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus.
Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus,
ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam
pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus congue quam,
in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien
mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis
eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim
interdum, justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus
dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras
ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque
egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur
consectetuer.
Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum
eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu
ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie non, nonummy vel,
nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales
cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed ultricies
auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla.
Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor odio, commodo
pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est,
nonummy in, fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio.
Sed commodo posuere pede. Mauris ut est. Ut
quis purus. Sed ac odio. Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio.
Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan risus eget odio. In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. Pellentesque non elit. Fusce sed justo eu urna porta
tincidunt. Mauris felis odio, sollicitudin sed, volutpat a, ornare
ac, erat. Morbi quis dolor. Donec pellentesque, erat ac sagittis
semper, nunc dui lobortis purus, quis congue purus metus ultricies
tellus. Proin et quam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Praesent sapien
turpis, fermentum vel, eleifend faucibus, vehicula eu, lacus.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec odio elit,
dictum in, hendrerit sit amet, egestas sed, leo. Praesent feugiat
sapien aliquet odio. Integer vitae justo. Aliquam vestibulum
fringilla lorem. Sed neque lectus, consectetuer at, consectetuer
sed, eleifend ac, lectus. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eget lectus.
Proin eu metus. Sed porttitor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
Suspendisse eu lectus. Ut mi mi, lacinia sit amet, placerat et,
mollis vitae, dui. Sed ante tellus, tristique ut, iaculis eu,
malesuada ac, dui. Mauris nibh leo, facilisis non, adipiscing quis,
ultrices a, dui.
Morbi luctus, wisi viverra faucibus pretium,
nibh est placerat odio, nec commodo wisi enim eget quam. Quisque
libero justo, consectetuer a, feugiat vitae, porttitor eu, libero.
Suspendisse sed mauris vitae elit sollicitudin malesuada. Maecenas
ultricies eros sit amet ante. Ut venenatis velit. Maecenas sed mi
eget dui varius euismod. Phasellus aliquet volutpat odio. Vestibulum
ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sit amet pede ac sem eleifend
consectetuer. Nullam elementum, urna vel imperdiet sodales, elit
ipsum pharetra ligula, ac pretium ante justo a nulla. Curabitur
tristique arcu eu metus. Vestibulum lectus. Proin mauris. Proin eu
nunc eu urna hendrerit faucibus. Aliquam auctor, pede consequat
laoreet varius, eros tellus scelerisque quam, pellentesque hendrerit
ipsum dolor sed augue. Nulla nec lacus.
Suspendisse vitae elit. Aliquam arcu neque,
ornare in, ullamcorper quis, commodo eu, libero. Fusce sagittis erat
at erat tristique mollis. Maecenas sapien libero, molestie et,
lobortis in, sodales eget, dui. Morbi ultrices rutrum lorem. Nam
elementum ullamcorper leo. Morbi dui. Aliquam sagittis. Nunc
placerat. Pellentesque tristique sodales est. Maecenas imperdiet
lacinia velit. Cras non urna. Morbi eros pede, suscipit ac, varius
vel, egestas non, eros. Praesent malesuada, diam id pretium
elementum, eros sem dictum tortor, vel consectetuer odio sem sed
wisi.
Sed feugiat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut
pellentesque augue sed urna. Vestibulum diam eros, fringilla et,
consectetuer eu, nonummy id, sapien. Nullam at lectus. In sagittis
ultrices mauris. Curabitur malesuada erat sit amet massa. Fusce
blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam euismod. Aenean vel lectus.
Nunc imperdiet justo nec dolor.
Etiam euismod. Fusce facilisis lacinia dui.
Suspendisse potenti. In mi erat, cursus id, nonummy sed, ullamcorper
eget, sapien. Praesent pretium, magna in eleifend egestas, pede pede
pretium lorem, quis consectetuer tortor sapien facilisis magna.
Mauris quis magna varius nulla scelerisque imperdiet. Aliquam non
quam. Aliquam porttitor quam a lacus. Praesent vel arcu ut tortor
cursus volutpat. In vitae pede quis diam bibendum placerat. Fusce
elementum convallis neque. Sed dolor orci, scelerisque ac, dapibus
nec, ultricies ut, mi. Duis nec dui quis leo sagittis commodo.
Aliquam lectus. Vivamus leo. Quisque ornare
tellus ullamcorper nulla. Mauris porttitor pharetra tortor. Sed
fringilla justo sed mauris. Mauris tellus. Sed non leo. Nullam
elementum, magna in cursus sodales, augue est scelerisque sapien,
venenatis congue nulla arcu et pede. Ut suscipit enim vel sapien.
Donec congue. Maecenas urna mi, suscipit in, placerat ut, vestibulum
ut, massa. Fusce ultrices nulla et nisl.
Etiam ac leo a risus tristique nonummy. Donec
dignissim tincidunt nulla. Vestibulum rhoncus molestie odio. Sed
lobortis, justo et pretium lobortis, mauris turpis condimentum
augue, nec ultricies nibh arcu pretium enim. Nunc purus neque,
placerat id, imperdiet sed, pellentesque nec, nisl. Vestibulum
imperdiet neque non sem accumsan laoreet. In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. Etiam condimentum facilisis libero. Suspendisse in elit
quis nisl aliquam dapibus. Pellentesque auctor sapien. Sed egestas
sapien nec lectus. Pellentesque vel dui vel neque bibendum viverra.
Aliquam porttitor nisl nec pede. Proin mattis libero vel turpis.
Donec rutrum mauris et libero. Proin euismod porta felis. Nam
lobortis, metus quis elementum commodo, nunc lectus elementum
mauris, eget vulputate ligula tellus eu neque. Vivamus eu
dolor.
```

Use this file in the document:

```
\usemodule[m-ipsum]

\starttext
    \ipsum[alternative=lines, file=mylorem, n=124]
\stoptext
```

Result:

[image]

Of course you can use any other dummy text file as well, if you want to save yourself the trouble of reformatting the LaTeX version.

Comment: very unfortunate that `m-ipsum` doesn't provide this functionality out of the box... it's making me second guess ConTeXt as a viable substitute for LaTeX...

Comment: @user32882 it would be a trivial change in the module code to start again at the first line when the full file is read, however I wanted to give an answer that doesn't involve changing the source code of an installed module. Of course you can request such a change via the mailing list for example. For LaTeX packages the situation is similar, there are bugs and issues that need to be reported one way or another that are subsequently fixed by the maintainer if they are active and willing to pick up the issue, otherwise the problem does not get fixed and you need to edit the code yourself.

Comment: However, from my limited experience with ConTeXt it does indeed seem the case that several things that are stable and feature-rich in LaTeX (such as the `lipsum` package, or similar packages on https://ctan.org/topic/dummy-gen) do not have a similarly stable and feature-rich ConTeXt equivalent.